# Code First using Visual Studio 2013 Template with Asp.Net Identity not working?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

Im working in this tutorial to update my **AspNetUsers** table with **Code First**.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

**This my IdentityModelClass:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace MTGWeb.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public String Pais;
        public String Email;
        public DateTime UltimoLogin;
        public DateTime FechaRegistro;
        public String Tipo;
        public Boolean Activado;

    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

    }
}
```

I already make this steps:

> - Enable-Mirations - OK
> - Add-Migration "BlaBla.."
> - Update-Database

This steps executes correctly (not stop on error) but not changes anything. I followed all the tutorial steps, with my custom data, and debuggin the data send ok across the viewmodels, but the database is the problem.

I see the Table AspNetUsers and not any fields are saved. Any ideas? I can register users but only save the default data (`Id, Username, PasswordHash,SecurityStamp and Discriminator`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity framework maps properties to columns. Right now they are fields. Change them to auto properties like this...

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public String Pais { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public DateTime UltimoLogin { get; set; }
    public DateTime FechaRegistro { get; set; }
    public String Tipo { get; set; }
    public Boolean Activado { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Oops! I forgive this detail! Thanks, sometimes we need other eyes :)